# Should I unit test "internal" classes?

Tags: unit-testing

In a server application, I have a class called `Controller` which receive the incoming request. I also have a class called `Service` which do business logic and a class called `Database`. All classes are "public", but only one of them is really reachable from the "outside", the `Controller`.

I am in a dilemma, should I only test the `Controller` since it is the only callable class or should I test all 3 classes separately?

Pros for testing only the `Controller`:

- Dead code easy to find, since it will not be covered
- Refactor won't break the tests, the `Service` class is only an implementation detail
- Some languages have the "internal" keyword that suggest that the class should be consider as an implementation detail, thus to be treated as private
- Tests won't overlap on each other

Cons:

- Harder to know how a method in `Service` and `Database` are tested
- It is the same an integration test
- Setup is harder since the `Controller` depend everything. By harder I mean that I will have to create a `Database` which will be injected into the `Service` which will be injected into the `Controller` vs only mocking the `Service` which will be injected to the `Controller`.

Comment: Can you precisely define what an _internal class_ is, according to you? You seem to define both `Service` and `Database` classes as _internal_, while some developers would simply call them _a class_.

Comment: It is a c#. java concept where the class is only visible inside the same assembly/package, thus not publicly accessible.

Comment: The crux of your question is whether your internal classes are or are not implementation details, which is ambiguous from your question. You claim they are, but in most contexts I can think of, I would believe that neither a `Service` nor a `Database` class is an implementation detail of a `Controller` class, merely that they are dependencies which I would assume are themselves tested in isolation. I think you should either revise your example or your usage of _internal class_ in order to clarify this ambiguity.

Comment: You are right sir! You made me realize that injected classes must be public, thus must be tested separately. I took my example from a python code, and I wrongly assumed that they were internal classes.

Comment: Re, "Harder to know how a method in ['internal' classes] are tested" Sometimes, that just means that you did not design those classes with testing in mind.  If you embrace [_test-driven development_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) then you won't often run into that problem.

Comment: You should test all things that need testing. Whether they're internal is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vincent Savard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/430618/should-i-unit-test-internal-classes#comment945322_430618) made me realize 2 things. That I have a design problem not an internal test problem and a public class is not necessarily API public.

If the `Service` and the `Database` are instantiated in the `Controller` I have a coupling problem.

If the `Service` and the `Database` are injected in the `Controller`, then they are public, thus they can/must be tested.

Answer (score 4):

Any class that is marked `public` (or `internal` or `package private` in some languages, which just means it's only publicly accessible in the same assembly or package) is eligible for unit testing, except for those classes stated below.

A test that tests a public class indirectly (i.e. through some API endpoint like a REST interface) is an *integration test*, not a unit test.

You don't have to test *private methods.*  Private methods can be tested indirectly using the class's public methods.

Here are the classes you should *not* unit test:

1. Nested classes; that is, classes within classes.
2. Classes with no behavior, like Data Transfer Objects.
3. Anonymous classes.

> Setup is harder, since the controller...

Then refactor the class so that it is easier to test.  One reason unit tests are valuable is that they point out deficiencies in your designs.

Comment: "*The metric is not "it is directly accessible to the outside world," it is that the class is a "unit," or more accurately, its methods are units. Hence the name "unit test."*". Completely disagree. The first metric to use when deciding whether to write an automated test for a particular piece of code is exactly is it directly accessible to the outside world. If it isn't then it's an implementation detail and should not be directly tested. The word "unit" is just an excuse for pointless semantics.

Comment: Then define what you mean by "outside world."  My definition of "outside world" is that the class is marked `public`.  The OP's definition of "outside world" is some sort of API endpoint like a REST interface.  My answer already states that you don't have to unit test `private` methods, and the rest of my answer goes into some detail about what does and does not need to be unit tested.

Comment: In any case, I've removed the "objectionable" content, since it seems to be confusing an otherwise straightforward concept.

Comment: The trouble is, you haven’t removed that objectionable content. Internal classes are implementation details. They should not be directly tested. So your advice that they should be remains bad advice in my view.

Comment: Not "internal".  `internal`.  It's a keyword in C#; it means "Accessible only within this assembly."  Classes within an assembly absolutely should be unit-tested; I don't consider this a controversial point.  That's why Microsoft provides the [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute;](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-5.0) it's specifically designed to facilitate unit testing of `internal` classes.

Comment: As [Mark Seemann says in an article on the subject](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/22/unit-testing-internals/), `InternalsVisibleTo` is part of the problem; not part of the solution. C# also supplies `goto` and global variables. Just because the language supplies it doesn’t make it a good thing. If you are directly testing a class makes `internal` then you are doin it wrong as you are no longer testing the public API surface.

Comment: Then I guess the remedy is to make all of your classes `public`, as it doesn't seem sensible to write a large collection of *untested* classes.

Comment: Anyway, I think you've gotten your levels of abstraction mixed up.  The argument against testing internals has always been about testing *methods internal to classes,* not classes marked `internal`.  The argument against testing methods internal to classes is not compelling either.

Comment: Nope, you have got yourself muddled as to what  a tested class is. Every line of every internal class should be testable via your public methods. If a line of code isn't testable via a public method, then it's unreachable code and needs removing. Testing internals directly can hide the fact that you have unreachable code, which is yet another reason for never directly testing internal code. It is irrelevant whether the code is in a private/internal method of a public class or an internal class: it is all internal code and therefore just implementation details and testing it directly is bad.

Comment: @DavidArno: thought experiment: imagine a larger, complex component with a very lightweight interface. For example, a math expression evaluator which >100k lines of code internally, and lots of `internal` classes, but exposing less than a dozen public methods. Testing such a component only through the public interface boils down to write no unit tests at all, only integration tests. Sure, every line of code is theoretically testable via the public methods, but that does not mean it is a good idea to do so.

Comment: ... note I am not saying what you wrote is completely unreasonable, but I think it makes a difference what kind of software one writes and how / for what purpose classes are marked as `internal`. When it comes to `internal` classes, there are 3 options of testing: 1. testing them only indrectly, through other public methods. 2. making them public for easier testing, or 3. using `InternalsVisibleTo` to allow direct testing. All 3 options can be reasonable, depending on the context, and the kind of software one writes, there is no hard-and-fast rule when to pick which approach.

Answer (score -1):

"Well, there are many different kinds of tests, and ways of running them."

*Every* class ought to –somewhere – have a "test rig" that thoroughly tests it. Even though that test rig constructs a thoroughly-artificial situation in order to do so.  But in the case of "internal" classes you probably need to run these tests only after a *change* has actually been made to that class.

The very worst thing that can happen to any house is **"foundation** problems."  Therefore, you need to know that the foundation ("inner classes") is solid, before you can meaningfully test anything that's built on top of it.  *"Okay, I see that this wall isn't quite square, but I know that the problem has nothing to do with the basement – I think that I can* ***eliminate*** *that possibility."*

(The ability to "think that you can eliminate that possibility" is **huge.)**

Build a series of "easily re-runnable test rigs" which can automatically perform the various test sequences that are needed (probably invoking other test-rigs in order to do so).  Maybe you don't "routinely run" all of them, but prior to a major release you should run "the test-rig that runs *absolutely everything."*